# HTML5/JavaScript based game - Controlling x/y coordinates with touch

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I am trying to make a HTML5 Canvas/JavaScript game. I watched some tutorials, and I understand what everying is meant for, but I don't get the right controls for touch devices.

I want to get my 'airship', where my finger touches the screen. It is not only working with where my mouse is positioned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {

            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var canvasWidth = canvas.offsetWidth;
            var canvasHeight = canvas.offsetHeight;

            var bg1 = new Image();
            var bg2 = new Image();

            bg1.src = "img/spritesheet.png";
            bg2.src = "img/spritesheet.png";

            var increment = -5;
            var sYbg1 = 0;
            var sYbg2 = 960;

            var ship = new Image();
            ship.src = "img/spritesheet.png";

            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;

            canvas.onmousemove = function() {

                    mouseX = window.event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft; // mousePositionX 
inside the <canvas> element
                    mouseY = window.event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;  // mousePositionY 
inside the <canvas> element

            };

            var animate = function() {

                context.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);


context.drawImage(bg1,0,sYbg1,canvasWidth,canvasHeight,0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

context.drawImage(bg2,0,sYbg2,canvasWidth,canvasHeight,0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
                sYbg1 += increment;
                sYbg2 += increment;

                if(sYbg2 <= 0) {
                    sYbg1 = 0;
                    sYbg2 = 960;
                }

                context.drawImage(ship,320,0,65,105,(mouseX-32),(mouseY-52),65,105);

                setTimeout(animate,25);
            };

            animate();

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="480"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

(!MY CODE IS ONLY WORKING IN CHROME!) --> But thats not important not, I know about the window.event and that it's not working in FF.

I hope someone can explain to me what I need to do. I tried to fix my problem to use onmousemove and onmousedown together, but that wasn't working for me too. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a hint, in case you haven't gotten there yet, and for future researchers. You have a mouse event handler (mousemove). I don't see a touch event handler. There are some options depending on your browser, which is unclear to me which you want to use...
However you can start looking at https://developers.google.com/  or MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ as good starting points.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really usefull for me. I didn't noticed that I needed some touch event handlers instead of the mousemove handlers. This kind of make sence to me right now. Thank you!